# MVC design pattern and asp.net mvc solution structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, dll

I have developped some asp.net mvc applications ( MVC 3,4 and 5). I
    used to have this solution structure :

- Asp.Net MVC which contains The view and the controller layers and the service (Web Api) and viewmodel sub-layers ( of the model
  layer)
- a BLL sub-layer as a library
- a DAL sub-layer as library

  So I have three dll :
- Web.dll referenced to BLL.dll and DAL.dll
- BLL.dll referenced to DAL.dll
- DAL.dll

  the problem is for example from controller I can get an entity from
  DAL and I can execute sql query then. It's a problem of security and
  abstraction.

  I draw this following schema in which the "arrow" mean **can see** ,
  **can communicate with** or **can use**. Any other connection were not permitted.

[image: mvc]

```
I need to know :

 1. Does the schema respect the MVC design pattern?
 2. How can I structure my solution to follow the schema architecture?

Thanks,
```

Comment: You have the arrow between BLL and DAL the wrong way around. The BLL should not be dependent on the DAL, the DAL should be dependent on the BLL. By this I mean that the BLL should be *defining how the contract (interface) is*, and the DAL should be *providing an implementation for said interface*.

Comment: What is the Service in the image?

Comment: @Maarten I assume that in DAL i implement repository pattern (interface,concrete,domain) to perform crud operations. in the BLL(bussiness logic layer), I assume that it contains the logic algorithms and mapping method between database entities (in DAL) and view Model entities

Comment: @Maarten the service is a sub-layer which definies and implement web services ( for example web api controllers if we use REST )